# How can I unit test a MassTransit consumer that builds and executes a routing slip?

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, masstransit, routing-slip

In .NET Core 2.0 I have a fairly simple MassTransit routing slip that contains 2 activities. This is built and executed in a consumer and it all ties back to an automatonymous state machine. It all works great albeit with a few final clean tweaks needed.

However, I can't quite figure out the best way to write unit tests for my consumer as it builds a routing slip. I have the following code in my consumer:

```
public async Task Consumer(ConsumerContext<ProcessRequest> context)
{
   var builder = new RoutingSlipBuilder(NewId.NextGuid());

    SetupRoutingSlipActivities(builder, context);

    var routingSlip = builder.Build();

    await context.Execute(routingSlip).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I created the SetupRoutingSlipActivities method as I thought it would help me write tests to make sure the right activities were being added and it simply looks like:

```
public void SetupRoutingSlipActivities(RoutingSlipBuilder builder, ConsumeContext<IProcessCreateLinkRequest> context)
{
        builder.AddActivity(
            nameof(ActivityOne),
            new Uri("execute_activity_one_example_address"),
            new ActivityOneArguments(
                context.Message.Id,
                context.Message.Name)
        );

        builder.AddActivity(
            nameof(ActivityTwo),
            new Uri("execute_activity_two_example_address"),
            new ActivityTwoArguments(
                context.Message.AnotherId,
                context.Message.FileName)
        );
}
```

I tried to just write tests for the SetupRoutingSlipActivities by using a Moq mock builder and a MassTransit InMemoryTestHarness but I found that the AddActivity method is not virtual so I can't verify it as such:

```
aRoutingSlipBuilder.Verify(x => x.AddActivity(
                nameof(ActivityOne),
                new Uri("execute_activity_one_example_address"),
                It.Is<ActivityOne>(y => y.Id == 1 && y.Name == "A test name")));
```

Please ignore some of the weird data in the code examples as I just put up a simplified version.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do this? I also wanted to test to make sure the RoutingSlipBuilder was created but as that instance is created in the Consume method I wasn't sure how to do it! I've searched a lot online and through the MassTransit repo but nothing stood out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how the Courier tests are written, there are a number of test fixtures available to test routing slip activities. While they aren't well documented, the unit tests are a working testament to how the testing is used.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.Tests/Courier/TwoActivityEvent_Specs.cs

Comment: I've been through these and they were how I managed to figure out how to write my activity unit tests but I couldn't see anything in there that helped in this scenario (i.e. testing that I have built my routing slip with the necessary tasks etc). Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I should probably add that I can use the InMemoryTestHarness to create and fire off my consumer it's just then being able to check that it setup the routing slip correctly.